# How to remove version from status.storedVersions while Manually upgrading the existing objects to a new stored version in k8s custome resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

How to remove version from 'status.storedVersions' while Manually upgrading the existing objects to a new stored version in kubernetes custom resources

apiVersion for CRD: `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Using aws EKS

CRD YAML

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  # name must match the spec fields below, and be in the form: <plural>.<group>
  name: crontabs.stable.example.com
spec:
  # group name to use for REST API: /apis/<group>/<version>
  group: stable.example.com
  # list of versions supported by this CustomResourceDefinition
  versions:
    - name: v1
      # Each version can be enabled/disabled by Served flag.
      served: true
      # One and only one version must be marked as the storage version.
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              type: object
              properties:
                image:
                  type: string
                replicas:
                  type: integer
  # either Namespaced or Cluster
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    # plural name to be used in the URL: /apis/<group>/<version>/<plural>
    plural: crontabs
    # singular name to be used as an alias on the CLI and for display
    singular: crontab
    # kind is normally the CamelCased singular type. Your resource manifests use this.
    kind: CronTab
    # shortNames allow shorter string to match your resource on the CLI
    shortNames:
    - ct
```

And upgrading the CRD to v2

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  # name must match the spec fields below, and be in the form: <plural>.<group>
  name: crontabs.stable.example.com
spec:
  # group name to use for REST API: /apis/<group>/<version>
  group: stable.example.com
  # list of versions supported by this CustomResourceDefinition
  versions:
    - name: v2
      # Each version can be enabled/disabled by Served flag.
      served: true
      # One and only one version must be marked as the storage version.
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              type: object
              properties:
                image:
                  type: string
                replicas:
                  type: integer
    - name: v1
      # Each version can be enabled/disabled by Served flag.
      served: false
      # One and only one version must be marked as the storage version.
      storage: false
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              type: object
              properties:
                image:
                  type: string
                replicas:
                  type: integer
  # either Namespaced or Cluster
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    # plural name to be used in the URL: /apis/<group>/<version>/<plural>
    plural: crontabs
    # singular name to be used as an alias on the CLI and for display
    singular: crontab
    # kind is normally the CamelCased singular type. Your resource manifests use this.
    kind: CronTab
    # shortNames allow shorter string to match your resource on the CLI
    shortNames:
    - ct
```

After disabling version v1 I want remove it from the versions list to do that I need to remove it from status.storedVersions how can i do that the kubernetes document does not give details about that

Comment: Could you provide more information? What K8s version are you using, what apiVersion for CRD did you use (apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 or  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1). Could you share your CRD Yaml? Are you working On-Prem (GCP/Azure/AWS) or local env like Kubeadm or Minikube?

Comment: @PjoterS provided the details you asked for

Answer (score 1):

There is also another another way of removing `status.specVersion` using cluster API.

Fields under status are modified via the status sub resource:

```sh
curl -d '[{ "op": "replace", "path":"/status/storedVersions", "value": ["v2"] }]' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
  -X PATCH \
 http://localhost:8080/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions/crontabs.stable.example.com/status
```

To access API you need to first connected to cluster [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried many various options on Minikube, Kubeadm, GKE but everywhere output was the same.

Unfortunately it is **impossible** using `kubectl` and docs `Remove the old version from the CustomResourceDefinition spec.versions list` is bit missleading.

Once a definition falls into `specVersion` it's impossible to remove it. `storage: true` puts it int the `storedVersions` list.

It was well described in [this Github thread](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/2196#issuecomment-560294302), especially comment from @sebgl.

> IUC correctly the way CRDs are validated, it seems impossible to
>   easily update a CRD in order to remove an old version.
>
> When a CRD is updated:
>
> - the list of expected storedVersions is built from
>     status.StoredVersions in the previous CRD + newer storedVersions in
>     the new CRD
> - this list of storedVersions is passed to a
>     validation function that checks all expected storedVersions are still
>     present in the new CRD
>
> All served versions in the history of
>   the CRD end up in the Status. Any update to the CRD Status is
>   impossible. Any update to the CRD versions that would consist in
>   removing a version that exists in the status is impossible.

However, he also mentioned it can be done by using [operator-lifecycle-manager](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/blob/5a5389cb8d831e79acade535d947d4ad4a5c40a7/doc/design/dependency-resolution.md#deprecateremove-a-version-of-crd).

Programmatically updating the CRD can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/2196#issuecomment-560318404). This would bypass validation of CRD `storedVersion`.